# Which texts do you recommend to learn about the work of Cantor?

Tags: reference-request, elementary-set-theory, infinity

A friend asked me if I know texts which talk about Cantor's Work on infinity and Set theory . 
And this is the reason Which pushed me to ask the question here .

I prefer if you recommend texts for reading " for those who are not interested in techincal and the rigorous point of view " and another texts for the mathematical study .

I mean , I ask you to recommend 2 kinds of books :

1- Books for the mathematical study as a real study with less required mathematical background as possible as his mathematical knowledge is that topics which is provided in the level of high school.

2- Texts for reading " about " the work of cantor , I mean texts for those who are not going to study the subject in depth nor in a rigorous way , but they want to know about the subject , texts for public  such that "ABC relativity" written by Bertrand Russel or " Brief history of the universe " written by Stephen Hawking .

He is interested in theories and points of view about infinity.

Comment: Dauben's book on Cantor is very good.  A biography, sort of, but an intellectual biography. The book is not very technical. However, it will be useful to know *some* set theory before reading it.

Comment: Start with the Wikipedia article about Cantor. It has a lot of references.

Comment: Nice to see you Maths. Viva Egypt! ;)

Comment: @BabakS. , I hope so :) ok I will remove all of my comments :) politics is prevented here haha !

Answer (score 2):

Looking for a fun angle? Try Raymond Smullyan's *Satan, Cantor and Infinity*. I don't know if I've read this particular book, but judging from some of his other works, it should be pretty good!

Answer (score 2):

The book Georg Cantor - His Mathematics and Philosophy of the infinite by Jospeh Dauben would be my recommendation.